Homotopy groups of pointed spaces
We are following the book "Algebraic topology from a homotopical viewpoint" of Marcelo Aguilar, Samuel Gitler, and Carlos Prieto.
Already early in the book in 3.4 we showed that $\pi_n(X,x_0) = \pi_n(X)$. The proof was just elementary saying that a map $f: (D^n,S^{n-1}) \to (X,x_0)$ is just equivalent to a map $f\colon \frac{D^n}{S^{n-1}} = S^n \to X$ hence the equality follows (or more precisely it is a bijection).
Now in the new chapter 4.4 "Pointed and unpointed homotopy classes," the big theorem at the the end of this chapter says that if $\omega$ is a path between $x_0, x_1$ then we get an isomorphism $$\pi_n(X,x_0) \to \pi_n(X,x_1)$$
with some good properties. The proof here is much more involved and uses concepts like cofibration and fibration. My question is why are the authors doing this. Does not just inmediatly follow from the above proof that $\pi_n(X,x_0) = \pi_n(X) = \pi_n(X,x_1)$ and we don't need any path between them. What exactly is the nicer thing in this approach.
(My idea but I am not sure about this: Is here the striking point maybe that in the second case we get a isomorphism of groups? If so why is the map in the first approach not an isomorphism?)

If $x_0 \ne x_1 \in X$ then the equation $\pi_n(X,x_0)=\pi_n(X,x_1)$ is false. In fact their underlying sets are disjoint: elements of the left hand side are based homotopy classes of maps with base point $x_0$; but elements of the right are based homotopy classes maps with base point $x_1$.

And I don't know what you mean by $\pi_n(X)$.

In the topic of algebraic topology, being careful with set theory is important.

(You do have $\pi_n(X, x_0) = \pi_n(X, x_1)$ if you work in univalent foundations, as this just means $\pi_n(X, x_0) \simeq \pi_n(X, x_1)$.)

The authors consider pointed spaces.

2.7.1 Convention. From here on, we shall be concerned mainly with pointed spaces and pointed maps. We shall use the notation $M_∗(X, Y)$ for the set of pointed maps from $X$ to $Y$ endowed with the compact-open topology. Analogously, we shall use the notation $[X, Y ]_∗$ for the set of pointed homotopy classes of pointed maps from $X$ to $Y$, namely for the set $[X, x_0; Y, y_0]$.


2.10.9 Definition. The set of pointed homotopy classes $π_n(X) = [S^n,X]_∗$ is a group, called the $n$-th homotopy group of $X$.

Thus  $π_n(X)$ involves a basepoint $x_0 \in X$. Instead of $\pi_n(X)$ one should more precisely write $\pi_n(X,x_0) = [(S^n,s_0),(X,x_0)]_*$, where $s_0 \in S^n$ is a fixed basepoint.

3.4.1 Definition. Let $(X,A)$ be a pair of pointed spaces with base point $x_0 ∈ A ⊂ X$. For $n ≥ 1$ we define
$$π_n(X,A) = [Σ^{n−1}(I, ∂I); X,A]_∗ ,$$
where $Σ^k(I, ∂I) = (Σ^kI,Σ^k(∂I)) ≈ (D^{k+1}, S^k)$, where $D^{k+1} ⊂ \mathbb R^{k+1}$ is the unit disk and where $[−;−]_∗$ represents the set of pointed homotopy classes of pairs.

Instead of $π_n(X,A)$ one should again more precisely write $π_n(X,A,x_0)$.
There is in fact a canonical isomorphism $π_n(X, \{x_0\}) \cong π_n(X)$, but both sides involve the same basepoint $x_0 \in X$. More precisely on should write $π_n(X, \{x_0\},x_0) \cong π_n(X,x_0)$.
The proof is elementary, but note that on the LHS we have the homotopy group of a pointed pair (namely $(X,\{x_0\},x_0)$) and on the RHS the homotopy group of a pointed space (namely $(X,x_0)$).

thank you for your answer. Unfortunatly I do not understand the point. $\pi_n(X) = [S^n,X]$ while $\pi_n(X,A) = [D^{n},S^{n-1};X,A]$. As I showed above and as you say it is easy to see that $\pi_n(X,x_0) = \pi_n(X)$ are isomorphic groups (in fact I only showed that there is a bijection, is that also an isomorphism?). I don´t understand your point with "the non trivial part is..." Again the question what exactly is new in that theorem I cited of chapter 4.4 and does it not directly follow from what we said?

Ahh I think I understand now, the definition of $\pi_n(X)$ depends on $x_0$ so when writing $\pi_n(X,x_0) = \pi_n(X)$ this is not the same thing as $\pi_n(X,x_1) = \pi_n(X)$. Is this correct. Is there maybe a good example where the fundamental groups fixe different basepoints are not the same?

@user1072285 For a path connected $X$ all groups $\pi_n(X,x)$, $x \in X$, are isomorphic. This is proved in your book. However, for $x \ne x'$ the groups $\pi_n(X,x)$ and $\pi_n(X,x')$ cannot be identical (they are different already on the level of sets).
